# Close access to a dll in Excel

Tags: c++, excel, vba, dll

I'm currently working on a project using C++ and Excel. I made a DLL to export a C++ function in Excel. My problem is that when I test my function in Excel and I want to modify my DLL, I need to quit Excel because it's still running the .dll file, and Visual studio C++ can't delete the previous DLL to make an other.

It's a bit annoying to close and launch again Excel everytime so I would like to know if there is a way to close access to the Dll when the VBA script is finished.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't much of an option, since the DLL is loaded by Excel itself.

Comment: Did you tried adding/removing the reference at the begining/end of your VBA script?

Comment: If you type `End` in the VBA Immediate window then that should do it. You can also put 'End" at the end of your VBA script which sometimes unloads the DLL but not always I find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method you could use is to run a separate excel instance and automate opening/closing excel like so... (this is pseudocode I typed it in browser)

```
Sub TestMyDll()
  Dim xl as New Excel.Application
  xl.Workbooks.Open "file"
  xl.Run "MyFunctionCall"
  xl.Workbooks(1).Close False
  xl.Quit
  Set xl = Nothing
End Sub
```

A second method would be to dynamically load and unload the dll. This is probably the method I would use. As a test I copied Winhttp.dll to a different directory and called it my.dll. Do not put the dll in the same directory as the workbook containing your code or excel will probably load the dll.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function FreeLibrary Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hLibModule As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As Long

'my.dll is a copy of Winhttp.dll in a directory other than where this workbook is saved.
'Calling this will result in an error unless you call LoadLibrary first
Private Declare Function WinHttpCheckPlatform Lib "my.dll" () As Long

Private Sub Foo()
    Dim lb As Long

    lb = LoadLibrary("C:\Users\David\Downloads\my.dll")

    MsgBox WinHttpCheckPlatform

    'I found I had to do repeated calls to FreeLibrary to force the reference count
    'to zero so the dll would be unloaded.
    Do Until FreeLibrary(lb) = 0
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: This did allow me to delete the DLL, but when I replaced it by the modified DLL then Excel crashed ... any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach that automates Excel open/close is to use your IDE's features (if it has them) to do this for you.

For example, CVF, IVF, and CodeBlocks each provide facilities to launch Excel and run your addin/dll (and debug in real time).

As an example, in CodeBlocks go to Project/Set Program's arguments ... . This will launch a dialog.  You put your xls file with full path in Program Arguments (e.g. C:\myexceltest.xls), and you put the paht to Excel in the Host Application field (e.g. D:\Apps\MSO\Office10\EXCEL.EXE .... or wherever your Excel.EXE is located).

Then just Run, or Debug, and it works automatically.  You can't change the DLL while your running it, but closing Excel either explicitly or from the IDE get's you back to your source code, make changes and just click Run or whatever in your IDE and Bob's your uncle Excel and your .xls will launch automatically.

If you have set breakpoints in your source, then running Debug in your IDE will allow you to debug your DLL in real time.

This should apply to any language (e.g. this works with Fortran DLL's also etc.)